How to render filtered messages?
I'm working on a real-time chat project but I'm having issues rendering the filteredMessages when a user searches for a term in their conversation. The messages are correctly filtered when I right the code a certain way but then it loses its ability to render a new message after I've refreshed the page and try to send a new message. Here is what I currently have that allows for real-time messaging:
Messages.jsx:
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import useGetMessages from "../../hooks/useGetMessages";
import MessageSkeleton from "../skeletons/MessageSkeleton";
import Message from "./Message";
import useListenMessages from "../../hooks/useListenMessages";

const Messages = () => {
    const { messages, loading, filteredMessages } = useGetMessages();
    useListenMessages();
    const lastMessageRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            lastMessageRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
        }, 100);
    }, [messages, filteredMessages]);

    return (
        <div className='px-4 flex-1 overflow-auto'>
            {!loading &&
                messages.length > 0 &&
                messages.map((message) => (
                    <div key={message._id} ref={lastMessageRef}>
                        <Message message={message} />
                    </div>
                ))}

            {loading && [...Array(3)].map((_, idx) => <MessageSkeleton key={idx} />)}
            {!loading && messages.length === 0 && (
                <p className='text-center'>Send a message to start the conversation</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Messages

I tried this but it didn't render the filtered messages nor did it allow for real time chat afterwards:
const Messages = () => {
    const { messages, loading, filteredMessages } = useGetMessages();
    useListenMessages();
    const lastMessageRef = useRef();

    const messagesToDisplay = filteredMessages.length > 0 ? filteredMessages : messages;

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            lastMessageRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
        }, 100);
    }, [messagesToDisplay]);

    return (
        <div className='px-4 flex-1 overflow-auto'>
            {loading && [...Array(3)].map((_, idx) => <MessageSkeleton key={idx} />)}

            {!loading && messagesToDisplay.length > 0 &&
                messagesToDisplay.map((message) => (
                    <div key={message._id} ref={lastMessageRef}>
                        <Message message={message} />
                    </div>
                ))
            }

            {!loading && messagesToDisplay.length === 0 && (
                <p className='text-center'>Send a message to start the conversation</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
 };

